# Minecraft 1.16.5 how to summon a falling block(hopper) rotated in any direction?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to build a building in Minecraft 1.16.5 using commands, and I don't know how to summon a falling block rotated in any direction.
The command what I'm using now :

```
summon falling_block ~-1 ~50 ~12 {BlockState:{Name:"minecraft:hopper"},Time:1}
```

Edited:
Or summoning the top part of the rose bush, or summoning which stair in are rotated  to any direction, or summoning the top part of the door, and things like that.

Comment: Are you sure this should be asked on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a minecraft summon generator. Something like https://mcstacker.net/ should have what you need.